# Soft edges for interpolation output

Tags: qgis, interpolation, rasterization

I've built the following heatmap using `QGis 2.8.2`'s `Raster->Interpolation` feature. It looks almost the way I want:

[image]

*The background layer is Google Maps tiles by using the OpenLayers plugin.*

However, as you may see, the outer edges abruptly end, since it's basically a rectangle. I would to produce an output that **would not crop the edges** like this and would give a more organic output, following the outer points, like the following:

[image]

Does anyone know how could I accomplish this with QGis and or related tools?

Comment: Where did the bottom image come from?

Comment: I found this post about [heatmaps](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html).  He uses a heat map plugin that does seem to get the organic shape you are after - see point 12 in the link provided.

Comment: I drew it using Photoshop. It's just a way to communicate how I want it to look like. Thanks for the link! I'll try it out and let you know if it suits my needs.

Comment: TsvGis, the heatmap plugin doesn't quite create the kind of viz. I want. It looks better suited for heatmaps that represent density of points. The interpolation feature actually creates a better viz. for what I want. The missing piece now is, how to clip the outer edges to the contour, instead of cropping to a rectangle like it usually does?

Comment: I guess I will have to somehow clip the raster. I just don't know how, yet.

Comment: What is the dataset are you using? Is it related to height? Also, do you have data further out from your area of interest?

Comment: No, not related to height. The data is simple, just a set of real-state listings with lat, lon and a price. The weight is the price. The bounding box might be focused into a neightborhood, for example, but the user might navigate around the map, but the data shouldn't change based off the current viewport or zoomlevel.

Comment: Could you then create a clip polygon based of boundaries of suburbs, zones, counties or districts?

Comment: I updated the sample image of how I'd like the viz. to look like. I probably didn't communicate it well at first. Clipping might not be the term / way to go, because if I clip to a polygon, it will probably still looked cropped, unless I can get the polygon of the edge of the points somehow and then clip to it. I have no idea if how to do that, though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you create buffers (using dissolved buffer results) of the points based on varying distances (us a a field in the attribute table - "buffer distance field) by price. That might give you a similar shape to your example that you   could then use as a clip

Comment: How would I do that and using what tools?

Comment: All this can be done in QGIS. If you got Vector>Geoprocessing Tools>Buffer(s), that will open the buffer tool. The Input vector layer will be your points. You can have a set distance (eg all buffers will be 5m) or varying distances (based on a field you create in the attribute table with the distances you want). Ensure that you check the Dissolve buffer results so that any overlapping buffers are merged as one. Give that a try

Comment: It basically only created a big circle: http://bit.ly/1gnN8R2. Here are the original points: http://bit.ly/1VNMAUA, and the settings I used: http://bit.ly/1gnN5Vk. Also, I'd like it to be based off the `price` attribute. Is it really possible to interpolate and create a heatmap'ish viz. using this feature?

Comment: Is your data in decimal degrees (eg, lat/long: -23.122345,143.12345)

Comment: Yes: http://bit.ly/1H3WoyD.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26412/discussion-between-fullofcaffeine-and-tsvgis).

Answer (score -2):

Google Map using heatmap, not interpolation, its quite different. Layer heatmap is colored with point by point data, more data that you have in such area, more intend colour will be showed